# When adding an old position in Developer Story, the field Company Name stays with the last value added

Tags: bug, developer-story, meta

When the user adds a position in **Developer Story** and this position is an old position, the field *Company Name* stays with the last position added.

Step by step to reproduce:

[image: GIF of problem]